# Get Http Response

Tags: c#, sockets

I using `Socket` to get http response from `www.google.com.vn`

```
TcpClient c = new TcpClient();
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("74.125.128.94"); // www.google.com.vn
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ip, 80);
c.Connect(remoteEP);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(c.GetStream());
String s = sr.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

I do not get any results out. What's problem?

Answer (score 6):

You're not actually making a *request* - you're just connecting to the port.

*Either* write an HTTP request to the socket, or (preferrably) use [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9y35bd.aspx) or [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) so that you don't end up implementing an HTTP client yourself...